# configure static IP for static website on google storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I would like to configure a static IP for my bucket in google cloud storage... Is this possible without having VM instance just like what would happen when hosting my website on Godaddy or other alternatives?

We are sister companies working on business environment where internet traffic should be denied by firewalls, in the mean while we would like to open the IP:80 for accessing only a single website.

Kind Regards,

Answer (score 1):

There is no option to assign a static IP address directly to a Cloud Storage bucket. What you can do though to fit your need is to create a [Load Balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/adding-a-backend-bucket-to-content-based-load-balancing) in front of your bucket and assign a static IP to that Load Balancer. This is also one of the recommended way to [serve your content over HTTPS](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/troubleshooting#https).